# Writing Remote Images to Disk in Node Webkit

Tags: node.js, webkit, node-webkit

How would you write images to disk without making new request from server in node webkit?

Like opening this, how to save all already loaded images to disk without re-requesting from server?

```
var win = gui.Window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=google&tbm=isch', {
  position: 'center',
  width: 1024,
  height: 768
});
```